# Fail to upload with PHP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Trying to get a file upload program to work but keep getting "move_uploaded_file function failed". I set the permissions on the directory I'm trying to move files to, to 777. I have the file_uploads set to On and post_max_size set to 10G in my php.ini config file. I am also not filtering for any specific file type. But, any file type fails to upload. Please help. Thanks. The code originated from the following online tutorial: http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/File-Upload-Progress-Bar-Meter-Tutorial-Ajax-PHP

html with Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function _(el) {
                return document.getElementById(el);
            }
            function uploadFile() {
                var file = _("file1").files[0];
                //alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
                var formdata = new FormData();
                formdata.append("file1", file);
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.upload.addEventListener("process", progressHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
                ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
                ajax.send(formdata);
            }
            function progressHandler(event) {
                _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
                var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
                _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
                _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
            }
            function completeHandler(event) {
                _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
                _("progressBar").value = 0;
            }
            function errorHandler(event) {
                _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
            }
            function abortHandler(event) {
                _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>HTML5 File Upload Progress Bar Tutorial</h2>
        <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
            <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
            <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width: 300px;"></progress>
            <h3 id="status"></h3>
            <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

file_upload_parser.php

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "test_uploads/$fileName")) {
    echo "$fileName upload is complete";
} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: Quick test: try changing `"test_uploads/$filename"` to `"test_uploads/{$filename}"` and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I still get the "move_uploaded_file function failed" error. I can see when inspecting in the browser I am getting a 200 response from file_upload_parser.php with a type of xhr.

Answer (score 0):

i have tested code that you paste here. 
one things i found that there is typo mistake for complete handler function 
function name is `completeHandler` and event completeHander  is `ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHander, false);`

after fixing this mistake its running properly on my machine.
can you please fix and try again? @martinb

below is latest code for index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function _(el) {
                return document.getElementById(el);
            }
            function uploadFile() {
                var file = _("file1").files[0];
                //alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
                var formdata = new FormData();
                formdata.append("file1", file);
                var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
                ajax.upload.addEventListener("process", progressHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
                ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
                ajax.open("POST", "file_upload_parser.php");
                ajax.send(formdata);
            }
            function progressHandler(event) {
                _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
                var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
                _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
                _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
            }
            function completeHandler(event) {
                _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
                _("progressBar").value = 0;
            }
            function errorHandler(event) {
                _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
            }
            function abortHandler(event) {
                _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>HTML5 File Upload Progress Bar Tutorial</h2>
        <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1"><br>
            <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="uploadFile()">
            <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width: 300px;"></progress>
            <h3 id="status"></h3>
            <p id="loaded_n_total"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And code for file_upload_parser.php

```
<?php
$fileName = $_FILES["file1"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["file1"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["file1"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["file1"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
    echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
    exit();
}
if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "test_uploads/$fileName")) {
    echo "$fileName upload is complete";
} else {
    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
}
?>
```

Comment: I can confirm that. Fixed typo, created directory "test_uploads", set permissions to 777, tested it and it was working.

Comment: I corrected the typo but still getting "move_uploaded_file function failed".

Comment: Is "test_uploads" located in the same directory as your file_upload_parser.php?

Comment: can you please try `copy($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], "test_uploads/".$fileName);` ? @martinb

Comment: yes. I disabled the firewall. I'm using CentOS 7. I didn't make any changes to apache2. Whatever the apache defaults are is what I'm running. And I'm testing with small files.

Comment: @martinb can you please check whether `file_uploads` is on of off?  on php.ini file?

Comment: It is set to On. It doesn't even try to upload it seems. I'm I calling the uploadFile() correctly in the onclick attribute?

Comment: yes its correct. have tried `copy($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], "test_uploads/".$fileName);` function instead of  `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: As your code is working for us, there can't be any problem with the code itself. Try and add some error handling at the top of your php code: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` and see if it gives you some more information.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. When checking /var/log/messages I saw a selinux preventing message. I disabled and will reboot to see.

Comment: It was selinux blocking the upload. Thank you all for the feedback. The progress bar and the text that is supposed to show the amount of data being uploaded doesn't show anything. Does that work for anyone?

Comment: its working you have to upload large file then you will see that.